# Sign Up Form and Email Activation tutorial from developPHP.com

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

I am currently learning while following tutorials on developphp.com, im up to episode 6 in the bunch of videos and i've ran into problem and i just don't know what to do. Here is the video that i'm currently on, http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1294. i've watched the video 5 times now and i just cant work out what ive done wrong, my guess is because i've added a few more fields into the database then, what i thought was 'carefully' amended the code where it seemed needed.

if you haven't watched the video basically its a registration form using js & ajax and im up to the point of when entering data, making sure its the appropriate data for that specific field. What is supposed to happen is, when someone types in a username, it can't begin with a number and cannot be the same as another person, but as there is no other person in the data base that is a bit hard to do, but if you have done something wrong an error is supposed to appear by the side of the input field, if you enter a username and it doesn't, firstly a checking sign appears, then a success msg saying that username is god for use. after messing with the code, including trying to prepare statements, i get the checking msg but never the success and if i put something thats not allowed, again i get the checking msg but not the warning/failed msg and as im new to really using js and ajax,i don't really no where to start, i seem to thrown myself in at the deep end :\ ...

on the tutorial the guy put all the code onto one single page and he gives the code for you to be able to copy, so i tried putting the code on separate pages to keep the code on the pages to little as possible so its readable and neater for me. didnt work so i even tried it all on one single page and still didnt work..

Firstly ill give all my db fields then ill give my code, for the actually page, the js and the ajax called functions(if thats how ever its said)..

```
id | email | password | fname | lname | username | gender | city | country | website | userlevel | avatar | ip | signup| lastlogin | notescheck | activated
```

The form on my register.php..

```
<h3>Sign Up Here</h3>
<form name="signupform" id="signupform" onsubmit="return false;">
<!-- First Name -->
<div>First Name:</div>
<input id="first" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="88">
<!-- Last Name -->
<div>Last Name:</div>
<input id="last" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="88">
<!-- Email -->
<div>Email Address:</div>
<input id="email" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="88">
<!-- Username -->
<div>Username: </div>
<input id="username" type="text" onblur="checkusername()" onkeyup="restrict('username')" maxlength="16">
<span id="unamestatus"></span>
<!-- Password -->
<div>Create Password:</div>
<input id="pass1" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
<!-- Confirm Paassword -->
<div>Confirm Password:</div>
<input id="pass2" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
<!-- Gender -->
<div>Gender:</div>
<select id="gender" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="m">Male</option>
  <option value="f">Female</option>
</select>
<!-- City -->
<div>City:</div>
<input id="city" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
<!-- Country -->
<div>Country:</div>
<select id="country" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
  <?php include "page_includes/reg/country_list.php"; ?>
</select>
<!-- Terms and Conditions -->
<div>
  <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="openTerms()">
    View the Terms Of Use
  </a>
</div>
<div id="terms" style="display:none;">
  <h3>Socio Terms Of Use</h3>
  <p>1. bla bla bla.</p>
  <p>2. bla bla bla.</p>
  <p>3. bla bla bla.</p>
</div>
<!-- Register Button -->
<br /><br />
<button id="signupbtn" onclick="signup()" class="btn btn-md btn-success">Create Account</button>
<span id="status"></span>
</form>
```

This is the code for register.js

```
//Register JavaScript
//Restrict
function restrict(elem){
  var tf = _(elem);
  var rx = new RegExp;
  if(elem == "email"){
rx = /['' ""]/gi;
} else if(elem == "username"){
rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
}
tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, "");
}
//Empty Element
function emptyElement(x){
_(x).innerHTML = "";
}
//Check Username
function checkusername(){
var u = _("username").value;
if(u != ""){
 _("unamestatus").innerHTML = '<strong class="alert alert-info" style="width:50%;display:inline;">checking ...</strong>';//@ the ... can insert a image or a loading .gif to give some animation...
 var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "./page_includes/reg/signupajax.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
          _("unamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
      }
    }
    ajax.send("usernamecheck="+u);
  }
}
//Sign Up
function signup(){
var f = _("first").value;
var l = _("last").value;
var u = _("username").value;
var e = _("email").value;
var p1 = _("pass1").value;
var p2 = _("pass2").value;
var ci = _("city").value;
var co = _("country").value;
var g = _("gender").value;
var status = _("status");
if(f =="" || l == "" || u == "" || e == "" || p1 == "" || p2 == "" || ci == "" || co == "" || g == ""){
status.innerHTML = '<strong class="alert alert-danger" style="width:50%;display:inline;">Fill out all of the form data</strong>';
} else if(p1 != p2){
status.innerHTML = '<strong class="alert alert-danger"  style="width:50%;display:inline;">Your password fields do not match</strong>';
} else if( _("terms").style.display == "none"){
status.innerHTML = '<strong class="alert alert-danger" style="width:50%;display:inline;">Please view the terms of use</strong>';
} else {
 _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
status.innerHTML = '<strong class="alert alert-info" style="width:50%;display:inline;">please wait ...</strong>';
var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "./page_includes/reg/signupajax.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
          if(ajax.responseText != "signup_success"){
      status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
      _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
    } else {
      window.scrollTo(0,0);
      _("signupform").innerHTML = "OK "+f+" "+l+", check your email inbox and junk mail box at <u>"+e+"</u> in a moment to complete the sign up process by activating your account. You will not be able to do anything on the site until you successfully activate your account.";
     }
       }
    }
    ajax.send("f="+f+"&l="+l+"&u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&ci="+ci+"&co="+co+"&g="+g);
  }
}
//Open the Terms Div
function openTerms(){
_("terms").style.display = "block";
emptyElement("status");
}
/* function addEvents(){
_("elemID").addEventListener("click", func, false);
}
window.onload = addEvents; */
```

here is the page with the ajax/functions on.. im only providing the first of the 2 as i the whole processing situation hasn't got to this part of the code, just the username checking point up to now...

```
<?php
$db = $GLOBALS['db'];
// Ajax calls this NAME CHECK code to execute
if(isset($_POST["usernamecheck"])){
$errors = array();
$username - $_POST['username'];
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username= ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($userid);
    $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->close();
if (strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 16) {
  $errors[] = '<strong style="color:#F00;">3 - 16 characters please</strong>';
  exit();
}
if (is_numeric($username[0])) {
   $errors[] = '<strong style="color:#F00;">Usernames must begin with a letter</strong>';
  exit();
}
if ($uname_check < 1) {
   echo '<strong class="alert alert-success">' . $username . ' is OK</strong>';
  exit();
} else {
   $errors[] = '<strong style="color:#F00;">' . $username . ' is taken</strong>';
  exit();
}
}
// Ajax calls this REGISTRATION code to execute
... code can be provided if really needed...
```

and there are to other pages of js that the guy doing the torial has provided code for that is used with this sitation the code for them are ...

```
function _(x) {
return document.getElementById(x);
}
```

and

```
function ajaxObj ( meth, url ) {
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open(meth, url, true);
x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "x-www-form-urlencoded");
return x;
}

function ajaxReturn(x) {
if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
    return true;
};
}
```

I know there is a hell of alot of code here, but i know someone who occasionally uses this and he suggested getting as much info as you can for someone to use is the best chance someone can help...

So basically my question is, can someone figure out why it wont work, and the best way to see what happens is  go to my site and see what happens ..http://howardmarstongroup.org/Socio/register.php

Comment: Try to write a short question

Comment: sorry, the question is short, just that the code that went with it was vast

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
```

The problem is with this, you're not using a placeholder yet you're binding a variable

change $sql to

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=? LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: sorry it already is, i just hadnt changed it when i put it on here but on my editor it already is a ?